# Passing a line of file into a linked list in c

Tags: linked-list

Hello guys I am trying to scan a line of file into a linked list and a line of data seems like this.

4-2-0 22 9 56
where the 4-2-0 should be string so a part of my code is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node{
    char comb;
    int mpn;
    int lower;
    int upper;
    struct Node *next;
};

struct MpnList{
    struct Node *head;
    struct Node *tail;
    int size;
};

typedef struct MpnList *list;

list Load_Mpn_Table(FILE *data){
list mylist = malloc(sizeof(struct MpnList));
mylist->size = 0;
mylist->head = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
int flag=0; //to check how many times while iterates.
if(mylist->head == NULL){
    printf("Out of Memory");
}
mylist->head->next = NULL;
mylist->head=mylist->tail;

data = fopen("data.txt","r");
struct Node *node = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
node = mylist->head;
//error in while loop
while(fscanf(data,"%s %d %d %d",&node->comb,&node->mpn,&node->lower,&node->upper) != EOF){
    printf("%d",flag++);
    node = node->next;
    struct Node *node = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

}


mylist->tail = node;


return mylist;
}
```

I get code.exe has stopped working (most probably memory) error and I think it is because the fscanf part.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This line looks wrong: `mylist->head=mylist->tail;`. Did you mean to write `mylist->tail=mylist->head;`?

The way your code is written, you replace the pointer to the first list element with an uninitialized value. After that, anything could happen (crash, lock up, corruption). It looks like you really wanted the list end to point to the first element that you just created.

Comment: I totally missed it thank you but it has still the same error :(